# How to install PDO extension on my xampp (windows)?

Tags: php, pdo

I searched for a while in this website but they say I need to install php, but i thought that when I installed XAMPP, php is also installed in that already.

I already search and placed the `;extension=php_pdo.dll`, though `;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` is already there, it can't find the driver.

Also in where part the extension directory will be found? I can't tell because when I searched it in my XAMPP there are 2 extension so I can't edit neither of them because it might get error somehow.

Comment: remove the `;` from both lines **extension=php_pdo.dll** and **php_pdo_mysql.dll** then restart xampp

Answer (score -1):

Usually, this extension has been installed in `Xampp`. I have faced this problem and it because I have 2 version of PHP installed in my system. I remove the first one and add the path of `PHP` of `Xampp` to my system variables path.
path of PHP in Xampp :
`C:\xampp\php`